# Correct ViewModel is provided, but wrong ViewModel is expected

Tags: razor, view, viewmodel

I kindof understand how Views and ViewModels work, but in the end I don't, because of the error below. Current view needs to view a list of users. The error says that the model is of type List, but some dictionary expects the model of type "LoginViewModel". The LoginViewModel was used for the login, that was one of the requests before. I confirmed with logging that both controller and view finish code execution to the very end. Delayed by a few seconds "Global.asax.cs" fires this error method:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

1. Why does the error below occur?
2. How does the Middleware connect Views and ViewModels?
3. What do I need to do, if I want to change the ViewModel to a different type, but not change the old type?

**Controller:**

```
[SecManAuthorize]
public class UserController : GeneralPageController
{
    [SecManAuthorize(permissions: Permissions.READ_USER)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<User> userList = GetUsers();
        return View(userList);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<User>
@using Namespace1
@using Namespace2
<div>
    ...
</div>
```

**Error:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Das Modellelement, das an das Wörterbuch übergeben wurde, besitzt den Typ "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace2.User]". Dieses Wörterbuch erfordert jedoch ein Modellelement vom Typ "Namespace1.LoginViewModel".
   bei System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   bei System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ConfigurePage(WebPageBase parentPage)
```

Comment: Somehow it wants the login page, investigate that.